# How to register an event "feature click" only for single click in openlayer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

```
map.events.register("featureclick", map, function(e){

}
```

I want to trigger this event only for single click not for double click.

Is it possible in openlayer? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below,

```
map.on('click', function(evt){

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {

            //yourCode ;


    });

});
```

When you click the map the code above will pass each feature its associated layer to the area marked //yourcode. You can then use an if statement against the layer variable if you only want this to work on features from a certian layer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the openlayers API if we use click event listeners on map, it will call twice for double click on map. For reference [see click event.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:click)

So I suggest to use **singleclick** event, it will not trigger twice when we double click on the map. For reference [see singleclick event.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:singleclick)

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {
        //yourCode ;
    });
});
```

**Note that this event is delayed by 250 ms to ensure that it is not a double click.**